# CFBridgingRelease ussage when assigning to a property - is niling it out necessary ("Crossing the Bridge")

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I am using a CFBridgingRelease when acquiring a network stream:

```
self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                       CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
                                       );
```

The property definition is:

```
@property (strong, readwrite) NSInputStream *networkStream;
```

In certain circumstances (when a proper streamEvent is received in the run loop) I finish the operation:

```
if (self.networkStream != nil) {

    [self.networkStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream close];
    self.networkStream.delegate = nil;
    self.networkStream = nil;
}
```

This is made as an NSOperation (adding to a NSRunLoop for a thread like AFNetworking one).
It is based on the Apple example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Should i make the

```
self.networkStream = nil
```

or will it be managed by ARC and the nil is unnecessary or even bad?
Also when I use the CFBridgingRelease is the Release made on acquire or when niling the value or how does it exactly work (I've done some reading and I k'now it is "passing the memory management responsibility to ARC" for an object acquired from CoreFoundation using "Create/Copy" as the "Create Rule"). Perhaps some more insight or info on it?
Thx in advance.

EDIT:

Ok.. Went through your comments but I have one issue mentioned

[NSStream error in specific configuraion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106017/crash-in-release-debug-ok-while-using-nsstream-ftp-apples-example)

In a nutshell => It works ok (even when trying to download an non existent file) but when the FTP server has bad rights  it crashes and only in RELEASE configuration. I added two pictures from instruments -> one when I do nil out the property and the other when I don't. 
Again - this only happens in RELEASE and in that specific FTP configuration!
This is tightly related so please if you have any ideas anwser on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
self.networkStream = nil
```

is not necessary, but it's not bad either.

ARC releases a resource when it's no longer needed, in other words, when there are no strong references to it, this means that the resource is released when you **set it to nil**, **or** when the variable referencing it goes **out of scope** (this should answer both your first and second questions).

In your case, since this variable is a member of your class, if you set it to nil it will be released immediately (to be precise, at the end of the current run loop). If you don't set it to nil, it will be released when your class is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

`CFBridgingRelease` does just what you say it does, your insight is fine. If you have an owned CF object which is one of the toll-free bridged types then you can transfer your ownership to ARC to manage. Despite the name, `CFBridgingRelease` doesn't "release" the object in the retain-release sense, it releases you from having to manage the ownership.

When it is no longer required ARC will relinquish your ownership of the object automatically, and if there is no other ownership interest that will result in the object being freed (released).

Assigning `nil` to a variable/property of strong reference type cannot be "bad" in the sense it could break memory management. Such an assignment simply relinquishes an ownership interest in the referenced object. Assigning `nil` is often unnecessary as ARC will relinquish ownership in a timely fashion; but, for example, if you have a property on a long-lived object you may want to assign `nil` to the property to relinquish your interest sooner.

Of course assigning `nil` can be "bad" in a program-logic sense if you actually need the object and the assignment causes it to be released!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

No need to set property to nil value. ARC will take care releasing that object.

CFBridgingRelease : It will transfer ownership to ARC, if passed object is Owned by you.(__bridge_transfer use this, while you are casting object)
CFBridgingRetain : It will transfer ownership to you from ARC(__bridge_retained).

If you don't want to transfer ownership, then you need to cast one objet to another object using "__bridge".

All object owned by you should be released after its Usage. It may be you received ownership by using CFBridgingRetain(), you should release that object.